# Building Python3 on a redhat 5 machine

Tags: linux, python-3.x, redhat

I am trying to build Python3 on a RHEL 5.7 machine, I successful managed to build Python 3.2.2, with :

```
# Install required build dependencies
yum install openssl-devel bzip2-devel expat-devel gdbm-devel readline-devel sqlite-devel

# Fetch and extract source. Please refer to http://www.python.org/download/releases
# to ensure the latest source is used.
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.2/Python-3.2.tar.bz2
tar -xjf Python-3.2.tar.bz2
cd Python-3.2

# Configure the build with a prefix (install dir) of /opt/python3, compile, and install.
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3
make
```

But I am failing (?) with Python 3.2.3:

```
Failed to build these modules:
_posixsubprocess
```

Is this a problem that should bother me ? How do I build it? 
I found [this patch](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/issue14359-posixsubprocess-o-compilation-error-on-CentOS-5-8-td4629652.html), but it's not included in sources Python 3.2.3 I obtained from the website ...
Applying this patch on my sources, didn't solve the problem ...

Comment: Well, I already answered my own question in serverfault.com: [building python 3.2.2 on a Red Hat 5 machine][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/388865/building-python3-on-a-redhat-5-machine/389622#389622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I already answered my own question in serverfault.com: [building python 3.2.2 on a Red Hat 5 machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/388865/building-python3-on-a-redhat-5-machine/389622#389622)

You need to apply the [patch found here](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/issue14359-posixsubprocess-o-compilation-error-on-CentOS-5-8-td4629652.html).

And then you can successfully build Python 3.